# Post created from AJAX call every sec without user input, html view?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

---

For the answer go there:

### [Render a view in rails via AJAX and controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42879546/render-a-view-in-rails-via-ajax-and-controller/42879768#42879768)

---

I have a rails app with a Post model where: new posts are created and saved; old ones are destroy; this is done automatically every 10 seconds from an AJAX call set inside an setInterval() function as follow in my application.js file:

```
var post_value = 0;
setInterval(function(){

        $.get('https://api.test', function(data){
            post_value = data.result.c[0];
        });

        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "/posts",
          data: { parameter: post_value }
        });

    }, 1000);
```

So far, so good, i can see that in the rails console every second the AJAX call saves new posts and destroy old ones. here is my controller: (The AJAX POST interact with the create action via a simple route: posts#create)

```
  def index
    @posts = Post.all
    @bet_last = Bet.last
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new
    @post.value = params["parameter"]
    @post.save  
    Post.first.destroy

    @last_post = Post.last
    @posts = Post.all

    render "index"

  end
```

Here is the corresponding html view: (index.html.erb)

```
<% @posts.each do |p|%>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row"><%= p.id%></th>
        <td>...</td>
        <td><%= p.value%></td>
        <td>Active</td>
    </tr>
<%end%>
```

My problem is that I want the html table rows to show without refreshing the page that post are added and deleted. 
I know that if posts where created from a form, I could use the data-remote=true and linked up the rest but in my case post are created in the controller without user input, so i do not have the normal set up as you would with a form.
How can I reflect the change in my html so that it can be shown dynamically ?

Thank you for your guidance.

PS: I can see that in the browser console, html is changed every sec but I do not manage to reflect that dynamically on the page, yet in the browser console it works.

**EDIT:**

Using the the following render in my controller (instead of render "index") does the trick:

```
render :js => "window.location = '#{root_path}'"
```

However it makes the page reload/refresh, which i do not want.

Comment: How do you access `post_value` from the `$.ajax` call when it's local to the callback of the `$.get` call???

Comment: I'm curious, do you have a `default_scope` in your Post model that grabs the current user from, say a Thread object, or do you just always destroy the first post no matter how many users are creating them?

Comment: Should it be more like this `setInterval(function(){ var post_value; $.get('https://api.test', function(data){ post_value = data.result.c[0]; }); ...`

Comment: @DominiqueFortin well because the post_value variable is inside the same function i.e (setInterval) as the AJAX call I make, I manage to grab with no issue, even though it is local to the $.get.  At least, that works but I do not have a better explanation for that.

Comment: @mmichael nope I just destroy the first post no matter what, no users involved. PS: I am testing things.

Comment: @Antoine I guarantee the you are not getting the value from the `post_value` declared in the callback of the `$.get` call.  You should check all references of `post_value` in your js code because this is a bug.

Comment: @DominiqueFortin my bad I put the wrong code, you are right my var is set outside setInterval

Comment: @Antoine You edited your post, but you forgot to remove the `var` in the callback of the `$.get` call.

Answer (score 0):

on you ajax call add success callback and update your html from there

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/posts",
      data: { parameter: post_value },
success: function(data){
// update your html here
}

    });
```

Comment: I tried to place an alert tag to try it out alert("test") and $("#ajax").html("<p>TEST</p>") Nothing happen.

Comment: I must miss something somewhere, something I do not understand

Comment: R u returining value fr server? you will need to return value

Comment: No, what do you mean ? I see the value in the console but the only way for my html to show the up to date posts is to refresh it. Which is what I do not want.

Comment: The `/posts` server must send the new list of posts back. Maybe in JSON format and the success function will update the html (write the js update code).

Comment: I got some news, I just realized that in the browser console I can see the that every second new html is created. now My problem is that it does not show on the view unless I refresh.

Comment: OK after testing more I believe I am not rendering correctly in my rails controller. I can see in the browser console that the html is changing but I am not rendering it.

Comment: it should be that.. I don't know about rails but my solution will work for HTML update..

Comment: see this simple example, I'm just updating counter here not response from server... https://jsfiddle.net/AbhinavWase/Lb8nnqg1/1/

Comment: it works because you are not interacting with any database, I believe.

Comment: no, its simple database call, your success function will have callback once you hit server for database update. We are doing it everyday, you just need to hit database into your ajax request, once updated successfully, your success function will be called.

Comment: you can simply user $.post method as you have used $.get see this for deails https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax_post

Answer (score 0):

I have open another question, clearer and better from all of my new understanding.
It is solved :-)

[Render a view in rails via AJAX and controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42879546/render-a-view-in-rails-via-ajax-and-controller/42879768#42879768)

I was failing in understanding the rendering in my controller:

```
def create
  # your logic here 
  render json: @bet
end
```